# Leaflet.js - GeoJson properties as icon

Tags: leaflet, geojson, image, icon

In this [map](https://marinespatialviz.github.io/marinespatialviz/Litter_Map.html) I am looking to display each image as a thumbnail from the GeoJson file.

For the moment I am using this code:

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: '<img src="feature.properties.description">',
      iconSize: [40, 40]
      });

var geojsonLayerP = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marinespatialviz/marinespatialviz/master/litter.geojson", {
         pointToLayer: function(feature, yx) {
           var marker = L.marker(yx, {icon: myIcon});
           marker.bindTooltip('<p>' + feature.properties.description + '</p>')
           return marker;
         }
       }).addTo(map);
```

But this does't give me the image as an icon. I know what I am doing wrong here, and I am looking for the right method to display each image as a thumbnail at the right location from the GeoJson file.

Comment: Looks like a typo when concatenating strings on the `iconUrl`. The `iconUrl` takes a URL, not a string of HTML. Use something like `iconUrl: feature.properties.description` instead.

Comment: In that case I only get a blank map... `var myIcon = L.icon({iconUrl: feature.properties.description, iconSize: [40, 40]});`

Comment: try: iconUrl: '<img src="' + feature.properties.description + '">',

Comment: Looks like error in url try `iconUrl: '<img src="' + feature.properties.description + '">',`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Comment: ...and what's the value of `feature.properties.description`?

Comment: Figured in the meantime: `var geojsonLayerP = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marinespatialviz/marinespatialviz/master/litter.geojson", {
         pointToLayer: function(feature, yx) {
           var icon = L.icon({
             iconUrl: feature.properties.gx_media_links,
             iconSize: [40, 40]});
             var marker = L.marker(yx, {icon: icon});
             marker.bindTooltip('<p>' + feature.properties.description + '</p>');
             return marker;
         }
       }).addTo(map);`